# How to Create Emulator tab in my project using AEM 6.1

Tags: aem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukKa2.png)

Hi friends just now I am starting to learn AEM I try to create an emulator in my project, but the emulator tab is not coming can you please help me how to create emulator tabs in my project

Answer (score 1):

Create a OSGI config for `com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.MobileEmulatorProvider` and add a list of templates for which the emulator should be displayed. The property that controls this is `mobile.resourceTypes`.

Refer https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/config/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/config.author/com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.MobileEmulatorProvider-core-components.config.